# .local/share/applications not overriding /usr/share/applications on my Kubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: kubuntu, kde, .desktop, menu

I’m having an annoying issue on my Kubuntu 20.04 install. I fail to to override a menu entry using KMenuEdit. It creates a file under “~/.local/share/applications” but it gets ignored and the original file under “/usr/local/share/applications” is the one that gets used.

It’s the same if I do all the edits manually. However, if I the file I place under  “~/.local/share/applications” has a different name than the one under “/usr/share/applications” it gets displayed on the menu.

I also already tested running “xdg-desktop-menu” forceupdate and "kbuildsycoca5” to make sure everything was up-to-date. $XDG_DATA_DIRS and $XDG_DATA_HOME environment variables also seem to be properly set.

I tested the Kubuntu 20.04 ISO on a VM and everything seems to be working well on the live session. I don’t know what else to do. Can anyone help me?

I'll add the example here that made me found this bug, however I've tried with other applications and the problem is exactly the same.

---

I use Google Chrome Beta which can be launched thanks to the /usr/share/applications/google-chrome-beta.desktop file.

However, as you may know, Google Chrome doesn't have a way to detect if your desktop is running in Dark Mode under Linux. Therefore, if you want to run Chrome in Dark Mode you have to add the "--force-dark-mode" command line argument.

So I decided to add that argument by editing the entry using KMenuEdit but it doesn't work. Google Chrome still launches in light mode because KMenuEdit creates a new file "~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome-beta.desktop" with the changes I made. Contrary to what it is supposed to happen the file gets COMPLETELY ignored and the one on /usr/share/applications is the one that gets to be used instead.

However, if I rename the file to something else other than "google-chrome-beta.desktop" I get two "Google Chrome Beta" entries. One is the original one that launches in light mode, the other is the modified one which launches in Dark Mode thanks to the "--force-dark-mode" flag.

---

Also, from what I was able to research there was someone else with the same problem on Manjaro: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/local-share-applications-not-overriding-usr-share-applications/89099 But they also seemed unable to fix the problem.

Comment: Please provide the actual details and are you sure it's `/usr/local/share/applications` and not `/usr/share/applications`?

Comment: @DKBose I fixed that. It was a typo on my part. I'll try to add an example.

Comment: I don't use .desktop files much. I've set up custom keyboard shortcuts for applications I use a lot. My shortcut for google-chrome-stable is this: `wmctrl -xa google-chrome || google-chrome-stable --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode --profile-directory=Default --start-maximized`. I've bound this to `Super+G`. The `wmctrl` bit checks if the browser is open but minimized and, if true, brings the window into focus.

Comment: Seems like a KDE bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=424716